# Python Element Tree - How to append value to child tag

Tags: python-3.x, xml, ubuntu

One of my linux software having configuration file in XML format,
This is the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configurations>
   <agentA>
      <trustedRepo>URL1</trustedRepo>
   </agentA>
</configurations>
```

The `trustedRepo` allow multiple URL entries which seperated by new line. All the while im manually editing this. And now I would like to seek a programatic way to do it.
I have search around the web, but cant get any similar use case.

I did a short script but not getting what i expecting

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as et
tree = et.parse('~/sw.conf')
root = tree.getroot()
tag = root.find('agentA')
a = et.SubElement(tag, "URL2")
print(et.tostring(root))
```

And I'm getting the URL2 been written as an element

```
<URL2 /></trustedRepo>\n    <URL2 />
```

Appreciate your solutions~

The idea output would be encapsulate URL1 and UR2 in same `<trustedRepo>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configurations>
   <agentA>
      <trustedRepo>
       URL1
       URL2             
       </trustedRepo>
   </agentA>
</configurations>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to an element text, simply locate the specific element and extend its `.text` with F-string interpolation. Below includes line breaks, tabs, and spaces for a pretty format:

```py
root = tree.getroot()
tag = root.find('agentA').find("trustedRepo")
tag.text = f"\n\t{tag.text}\n\tURL2\n      "

print(et.tostring(root).decode("utf-8"))

# <configurations>
#    <agentA>
#       <trustedRepo>
#         URL1
#         URL2
#       </trustedRepo>
#    </agentA>
# </configurations>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/NHPS62287)</kbd>

Comment: Appreciate your comment, however my SW unable to recognize if there is duplicate tag, ie two <trustedRepo>, i have added ideal output in my question